# Highcharts tooltip line height in styled mode

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to increase the line spacing in my Highcharts tooltip in styled mode. I have tried using CSS to set line-height on the .highcharts-tooltip as well as its text and tspan elements:

```
.highcharts-tooltip,
.highcharts-tooltip text,
.highcharts-tooltip tspan
{
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

I have also tried using the tooltip.style option:

```
    tooltip: {
        style: { lineHeight: 40 }
    }
```

Neither approach has any effect in styled mode. Has anyone managed to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `useHTML` property for a tooltip.

```
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    ...
  }
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/893k5cnL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML